# What is an Elegant Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

Really enjoyed creating this kind of puzzle, here's another one.

If a word conforms to a special rule I call it an Elegant Word™

| Elegant Words™ | Not Elegant Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| VISCOUS | FLUID |
| JOINING | MERGING |
| PUBLIC | PRIVATE |
| BIG | TINY |
| MUSIC | MOZART |
| GO | STOP |
| DOZING | WORKING |
| SUCCUBUS | SAINT |
| UNICORN | HORSE |
| POISON | TOXIC |

The CSV version: *(it won't help this time)*

```
Elegant Words™, Not Elegant Words™
VISCOUS, FLUID
JOINING, MERGING
PUBLIC, PRIVATE
BIG, TINY
MUSIC, MOZART
GO, STOP
DOZING, WORKING
SUCCUBUS, SAINT
UNICORN, HORSE
POISON, TOXIC
```

Can you tell me what the rule is?

Comment: These usually do better the longer the list is too, makes it a little harder (sometimes) to get right away. :)

Comment: True, but I was having trouble trying to come up with related words on the right columns with "I,O,U" vowels. Since using too much of A and E would be too obvious that the vowels are clearly segmented into Elegant and Not Elegant @n_palum

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An elegant word is a word where

> each letter can be written without stopping. Not elegant letters include T, F, E, K, H.

The csv version is unhelpful because

> the I is written as `I` and would therefore not be elegant.